# Uploading images to CKeditor in a file field way?

Tags: nodes, media, wysiwyg

### Background

I'm looking for one of the two possible solutions concerning image-uploading to Drupal, and especially to CKeditor image uploading and handling:

### Possible solution 1

A module that creates an independent image-folder to every node, uploads images to this specific directory, and then let me choose only between these images directly from CKeditor. If the node is deleted, than this folder is deleted along with it.

### Possible solution 2:

a module that uploads images into CKeditor text areas in an efficient, fast, Drupal-file-field-**like** way; It is important for me that this uploader will use the same rules like the Drupal file-field, the same mechanisms and SQL tables, so that when I delete the image I uploaded - it will be totally deleted from the site's home-folder.

So basically the uploader I'm looking for should do 2 things:

1. Upload files easy and fast, just like the Drupal file-field does.
2. Send some kind of signal when a file is deleted from that very CKeditor text area.

Please help me to find of these two possible solutions:

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Insert](https://www.drupal.org/project/insert) module is the standard way of doing this, it interfaces with ckeditor and allows you to insert images as an `<img src="">` tag but retain the file in the drupal file entity system.

**INSERT:**

> Insert is a utility that makes inserting images and links to files into text areas or WYSIWYGs much easier. It adds a simple JavaScript-based button to FileField and ImageField widgets. When used with ImageField and ImageCache, images may be inserted into text areas with a specific ImageCache preset.
>
> This module was previously known as FileField Insert.

An alternative way might be [paragraphs](https://www.drupal.org/project/paragraphs) module  which allows you to insert one or more images alongside text fields and theme them by layout (so text on left-image on right or vice versa) It's not ideal in all circumstances but works.

**PARAGRAPHS:**

> Paragraphs is the new way of content creation!
>   It allows you — Site Builders — to make things cleaner so that you can give more editing power to your end-users.
>
> Instead of putting all their content in one WYSIWYG body field including images and videos, end-users can now choose on-the-fly between pre-defined Paragraph Types independent from one another. Paragraph Types can be anything you want from a simple text block or image to a complex and configurable slideshow.
>
> Paragraphs module comes with a new "paragraphs" field type that works like Entity Reference's. Simply add a new paragraphs field on any Content Type you want and choose which Paragraph Types should be available to end-users. They can then add as many Paragraph items as you allowed them to and reorder them at will.

Answer (score 4):

I'm not 100% sure but maybe [insert](https://www.drupal.org/project/insert) module is a suitable solution for you.

**INSERT:**

> Insert is a utility that makes inserting images and links to files into text areas or WYSIWYGs much easier. It adds a simple JavaScript-based button to FileField and ImageField widgets. When used with ImageField and ImageCache, images may be inserted into text areas with a specific ImageCache preset.
>
> This module was previously known as FileField Insert.